# iOS: Local Storage using Core Data not persistent when I power off the iPhone

Tags: iphone, sqlite, core-data, persistence, storage

I am currently developing my first iPhone app. I used Core Data framework with sqlite to persist data, and everything is working perfectly, except when I power off the iPhone, I noticed that all data saved are lost.

So what's the problem here?

Comment: I've had this problem once and my cause ended up being that I wasn't loading the data on app launch, i.e. not querying for the top-level managed object, and instead creating a new one each time the app launches. Could be the cause?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any change you are forgetting to save the NSManagedObjectContext?

```
NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = ...
NSError *error = nil;
[managedObjectContext save:&error];
```

Also, check NSPersistentStoreCoordinatator is not using NSInMemoryStoreType as the storage type.

```
// Do not use the type below
[__persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSInMemoryStoreType configuration:nil URL:nil options:nil error:&error]
```